# Laravel 9 query builder TRIM()

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Hello i'm using a complex query with query builder and i was wondering how to use correctly the TRIM.
I have to use it in a LEFT JOIN
My code looks like this

```
        $data_db = DB::table('TCLIENTI AS TC')
                    ->leftJoin('REGIONI', TRIM('REGIONI.COD_REG'), '=', TRIM('TC.COD_REG'))
                    ->select(
                             'REGIONI.DESCRIZIONE' 
                             )
                    ->get();
```

It keeps returning null (by default it's correct) but i need to use TRIM for get the result that is present in that field

This is a the main trouble, there are some more joins and much more select in this query, so i would like to edit it as less as possible.

My question is why this is not working? I don't have any error

```
     ->leftJoin('REGIONI', TRIM('REGIONI.COD_REG'), '=', TRIM('TC.COD_REG'))
```

P.s. I'm converting an existing query from very old code that looks so:

```
Trim(TCLIENTI.COD_REG)=Trim(REGIONI.COD_REG (+))
```

Answer (score 0):

`TRIM` here is the PHP function [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) which will only trim the literal string you are providing i.e. `'REGIONI.COD_REG'` and will not actually trim the values in the DB column. You need to use a raw DB statement for that:

```
$data_db = DB::table('TCLIENTI AS TC')
     ->leftJoin('REGIONI', \DB::raw("TRIM(REGIONI.COD_REG)"), '=', \DB::raw("TRIM(TC.COD_REG)"))
     ->select('REGIONI.DESCRIZIONE')
     ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works! First time i tried this way but i had ' ' left DB::raw("TRIM('REGIONI.COD_REG')").